# Passing MIssingNode to ObjectMapper to convert to POJO

Tags: java, jackson, pojo, jackson-databind

I am converting a child node of a "root" JsonNode into POJO. If the POJO does not exist in JSON, this throws `MismatchedInputException`.

```
  JsonNode pojoJson = rootJson.path("pojoName");
  Pojo[] pojoArray = mapper.treeToValue(pojoJson, Pojo[].class);
```

I was wondering if there is more gracious way to handle this exception other than having to check with `has()` each time I want to convert a JsonNode into POJO?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the node type up front: `if (pojoJson != null && pojoJson.getNodeType() == JsonNodeType.ARRAY)` or even simpler `if (pojoJson != null && pojoJson.isArray())`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no way to do it "clear". Jackson doesn't have methods like `rootJson.path("pojoName", *defaultValue*)` or `mapper.treeToValue(pojoJson, Pojo[].class, *defaultValue*)`. But you have several options.

1) Use [`with`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#with(java.lang.String)) and [`withArray`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#withArray(java.lang.String)) instead of `path`.

Empty `ObjectNode` and `ArrayNode` will be returned with there methods. Empty array will be returned and no `MismatchedInputException` will be thrown.

But:

- `with*` methods not only return `*Node`. If no property exists, a new node will be **created** and **added** to your `rootJson`.
- Use `withArray` in case you are converting ObjectNode to array.

2) Use [isMissingNode](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#isMissingNode()) to detect missing nodes.

`path` method returns special [MissingNode](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/MissingNode.html) if no property exists.